# Showing for decidable language that is in $P/poly$ but not in $P$ (follow-up)

Tags: complexity-theory

I've been trying to wrap my head around the proof provided in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/what-is-the-decidable-language-in-p-poly-but-not-in-p) answer.
I understand that $P$ is a class where languages can be decided by a Turing Machine and that $P/poly$ is a bigger class that also includes languages that can be decided by circuits.

> Take a language $L$ which is not in $\mathsf{E} = \bigcup_{c=1}^\infty \mathsf{TIME}(2^{cn})$. Now consider the language
> $L' = \{1^m : m \in L\}$.
> Then $L'$ is clearly in $\mathsf{P/poly}$, but it's not in $\mathsf{P}$: if it were decidable in time $O(m^k)$, then we could decide $L$ in time $O((2^n)^k)$, and so $L$ would be in $\mathsf{E}$. Our decision procedure works as follows: on input $m$ of length $n = \log m$, we run the algorithm for $L'$ on the input $1^m$. This runs in time $O(m^k) = O((2^n)^k)$.

> It remains to ensure that $L'$ is decidable. To that end, all we need to do is to choose some $L \notin \mathsf{E}$ which is decidable, for that makes $L'$ trivially decidable: given an input, if it's not of the form $1^m$, reject; otherwise, answer according to whether $m \in L$.

> The existence of a decidable language $L \notin \mathsf{E}$ is guaranteed by the time hierarchy theorem.

I have a couple of questions about the understanding of this proof.

Then I am confused as to how we first define language $L$ to not be in $E$ and then we show that actually is in $E$ since $L^{'}$ can be computed within the limits...

Comment: $P$ and $E$ are not the same. By the time-hierarchy theorem $P \subseteq \text{TIME}(2^{n}) \subsetneq \text{TIME}(2^{2n}) \subseteq E$.

Comment: Oh thank you! But still, $L$ is firstly said to not be in $E$ but then we show that is runs in $O((2^{n})^{k})$ and hence is in $E$?

Comment: Are you familiar with proofs by contradiction? The answer is choosing $L \not\in E$ and then showing that $L' \not\in P$ by contradiction. To do so it assumes that $L' \in P$ and concludes that this would imply $L \in E$. Since this is indeed a contradiction (as $L \not \in E$), it must be $L' \not\in P$.

Comment: Ohh I see it now - I didn’t recognise contradiction through this structure

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Please ask only one question per post.  Please make sure to articulate your question explicitly.  A question normally ends in '?'.